# Passing varargin to nested class method in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, class, methods

I would like to parse variable inputs for several class methods in the same way, so I wrote a method to do just that and intend to call it from the other methods as needed. However, when I call `methodB` from `methodA`, `varargin{:}` isn't being passed as its cell contents but as another cell array – similar to if I hadn't included the `{:}`.

Does anyone have an idea why the contents aren't passing?

```
methods
    function varargout = methodA(obj,varargin)
        [obj,t.start,t.stop,prn,elevLim,t.interval] = methodB(varargin{:});
    end

    function varargout = methodB(varargin)
        % parse inputs here...

        %output parsed inputs to calling function
        varargout = {obj,t.start,t.stop,prn,elevLim,t.interval};
    end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you try to use your code as stated in the question, you will get error messages which would have been valuable to mention. In case you write `methodB(varargin)` this message is:

> Undefined function 'methodB' for input arguments of type 'double'.

And when writing `methodB(varargin{:})` it is:

> Undefined function 'methodB' for input arguments of type 'cell'.

The *main problem* here is that you have not *explicitly defined the first argument of `methodB` to be an **object** variable*. This is needed since `methodB` is a so-called [ordinary method](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/ordinary-methods.html) because it is not defined as static. There are some other problems in the code as well. For example `methodA` never assigns something to `varargout` and `methodB` should return `obj` which is not defined neither.

---

#### Solution with ordinary method

- `methodB` needs to have an explicitly defined object variable, so the first line of the definitition should be: `function varargout = methodB(obj,varargin)`. However, if we don't need `obj` in the method itself, we can replace it with `~`, so it dosen't get assigned to a variable.
- In order to call the method you need to use the proper syntax to call it, either `methodB(obj,varargin{:})` or `obj.methodB(varargin{:})`.

*Here is working code to verify it:*

```
classdef nestedvarargin

    properties
    end

    methods
        function varargout = methodA(obj,varargin)
              [t.start,t.stop,prn,elevLim,t.interval] = methodB(obj,varargin{:}); % call ordinary method (syntax 1)
%             [t.start,t.stop,prn,elevLim,t.interval] = obj.methodB(varargin{:}); % call ordinary method (syntax 2)
            varargout = {t.start,t.stop,prn,elevLim,t.interval};
        end
        function varargout = methodB(~,varargin)
            % extract desired values from varargin (for example leave 3rd argument out)
            varargout = {varargin{1},varargin{2},varargin{4},varargin{5},varargin{6}};
        end
    end

end
```

---

#### Solution with static method

- The other way is to define `methodB` to be static and call it as `baseclass.methodB(varargin{:})`. In this case, no explicitly defined object variable is needed.

*The code looks like this:*

```
classdef nestedvarargin

    properties
    end

    methods
        function varargout = methodA(obj,varargin)
            [t.start,t.stop,prn,elevLim,t.interval] = nestedvarargin.methodB(varargin{:}); % call static method
            varargout = {t.start,t.stop,prn,elevLim,t.interval};
        end
    end

    methods(Static)
        function varargout = methodB(varargin)
            % extract desired values from varargin (for example leave 3rd argument out)
            varargout = {varargin{1},varargin{2},varargin{4},varargin{5},varargin{6}};
        end
    end

end
```

---

#### Testing

In order to verify the functionality, you can use the following two lines. As defined in `methodB`, the third argument should be omitted as well as the arguments after the sixth (`5` in the case below).

```
testobj = nestedvarargin;
[a,b,c,d,e] = testobj.methodA(1,2,[],3,4,5,[])
```

The output is be as expected:

```
a =
     1
b =
     2
c =
     3
d =
     4
e =
     5
```

Comment: Thanks for two workable solutions Matt.  I implemented your first solution since I did need to use the `obj`.  Also, thank's for editing my original question for better formatting.  I'll use inline code formatting in the future.

Comment: You're welcome, thanks for the feedback... Consider [upvoting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) my answer if you find it useful as well since you earned the privilege now.